# Win10 can be remoted to destop(using mstsc) from Win8 or Win7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, remote-desktop, windows-10, windows-10-preview

I installed `win10 preview` ,then on `Win7` to remote to `Win10`(using mstsc),I can't using the any appliaction:
**just show the title bar but not show the content**.

Now, I  want to install `Win10` but I'm not sure whether `Win7` can remote to `Win10`?

Please give me a hand (Who have installed `Win10` and remoted from `win7`).

Comment: What build are you using precisely?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MSTSC to remote into a Windows 10 computer. You just have to check your Windows Updates and make sure you have the most up to date version of MSTSC. It is an Optional Update from Microsoft so your Windows 7 computer may not have it.